# how to get 4-days ago to now - php

Tags: php

If current date is 2016-03-06, I would like to get these dates :

```
2016-03-06
2016-03-05
2016-03-04
2016-03-03
```

I'm trying to get this purpose but my result not what I want :

```
$_4date = date("y-m-d",strtotime("day"));
$_3date = date("y-m-d",strtotime("-1 day"));
$_2date = date("y-m-d",strtotime("-2 day"));
$_1date = date("y-m-d",strtotime("-3 day"));

echo $_4date;
echo '<br />';
echo $_3date;
echo '<br />';
echo $_2date;
echo '<br />';
echo $_1date;
```

the result is :

```
70-01-01
16-03-05
16-03-04
16-03-03
```

Comment: Just use `date('y-m-d')` to get todays date. No need for `strtotime`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get today's date with `strtotime`, you do `strtotime("today");`. However, as *Bjorn* has commented, you can simply just call `date()` directly.

Furthermore, the reason you are not getting the year in four digits is because you are using a lowercase `y` instead of an uppercase `Y`.

Try `date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"));`.

The following piece of code illustrates the required changes:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"));

echo "$today <br />";
echo "$yesterday <br />";

// Output
2016-03-06 
2016-03-05
```

For more informtation, please consult the [PHP documentation on the date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). It actually shows you that what to expect from `y` and `Y` and it also shows you that the default value that is passed as the second argument is `time()`, meaning the default is the current time.

[PHP's strtotime documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can be consulted for more information on the `strtotime()` function and its possible parameters.

Always check the (PHP) documentation first before asking a question.

Comment: In addition you could create a array with the amount of disired dates by creating a for loop: `$dates = array(); $today = date("Y-m-d"); $days = 4;
for($i=0;$i<$days;$i++){ $dates[$i] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-".$i." day")); }
var_dump($dates);`

Answer (score 6):

You need to use like that:

```
$_4date = date("Y-m-d"); 
$_3date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 day")); 

$_2date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-2 day")); 
$_1date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-3 day"));
```

**Explanation**:

For current date no need to use use `strtotime()`.

For full year you need to use this format `Y-m-d`.
`y-m-d` will return you the date `16-03-06` but `Y-m-d` will return you `2016-03-06`.

Comment: it returns `16 ` instead of `2016`.

Comment: @s-m-emamian u need to use capital Y

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for` loop with `strtotime( "... days ago" )`:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 4; $i++ )
{
    echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( "$i days ago" ) ) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The first loop (`0 days ago`) will output today date, other loops will output past days.

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/pruvN)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$date = [date("Y-m-d")];
for($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $date[] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-$i day"));
}
//For cli output you'll need:
echo implode("\n", $date) . "\n";
//For web output you'll need:
echo implode("<br />", $date) . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use capital 'Y' for full year (2016) instead of small 'y' which will display year in shorthand (16).

And for current date just use `date("Y-m-d")`.

```
<?php

$_4date = date("Y-m-d");
$_3date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-1 day"));
$_2date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-2 day"));
$_1date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-3 day"));

echo $_4date;
echo '<br />';
echo $_3date;
echo '<br />';
echo $_2date;
echo '<br />';
echo $_1date;

?>
```

[Working Example](https://eval.in/531276)